# Why is TSP NP-hard while the Hamiltonian path NP-complete?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, np-complete, np-hard

Why aren't these 2 problems, namely [TSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) and [Hamiltonian path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem), both NP-complete?

They seem identical.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a problem X to be **NP-complete**, it has to satisfy:

1. **X is in NP**, given a solution to X, the solution can be verified in polynomial time.
2. **X is in NP-hard**, that is, every NP problem is reduceable to it in polynomial time (you can do this through a reduction from a known NP-hard problem (e.g. Hamiltonian Path)).

There are two versions of the **The Travelling Salesman Problem (TSP)**:

1. The optimization version (probably the one you are looking at), namely, find the optimum solution to the TSP. This is not a decision problem, and hence cannot be in NP, but it is however in NP-hard which can be proven via a [Hamiltonian Path reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1077436/the-traveling-salesman-problem-is-np-complete-reduction). Therefore this isn't an NP complete problem.
2. The decision version - given an integer K is there a path through every vertex in the graph of length < K? This is a decision (yes/no) problem, and a solution can be verified in polynomial time (just traverse the path and see if it touches every vertex) and so it is in NP, but it is also in NP-hard (by an identical proof as above). Since it satisfies both requirements for NP-completeness, it is an NP-complete problem.

Comment: So the optimization problem is NP-hard?

Comment: I think there's a couple of errors in your definitions. A decision problem may not have a solution that's verifiable in poly time (it's just any problem with a yes/no answer). NP-hard isn't defined in terms of other NP-hard problems (although your definition is sufficient, it's not necessary) -- the definition is that every NP problem is reduceable to it in poly time.

Comment: @PaulHankin Yes of course you are correct, thanks very much for your comment. For the NP-hard definition I just wanted to give an intuitive definition, and the step required to prove a problem X is in NP-hard. I updated my answer.

Comment: Question: For a TSP decision problem, assume that the answer is no. How would you check that in polytime?

Comment: @wjmccann by traversing the given solution and verifying that it is indeed "no". You can't just simply say "no" -- you need to provide a proof for why the answer is "no" -- from there you can simply check it, and it is in poly time because you just need to traverse n nodes from the solution.

Answer (score 6):

The definitions of NP-hardness and NP-completeness are related but different. Specifically, a problem is NP-hard if every problem in NP reduces to it in polynomial time, and a problem is NP-complete if it's both NP-hard and itself in NP.

The class NP consists of decision problems, problems that have a yes/no answer. As a result, TSP cannot be in NP because the expected answer is a number rather than yes or no. Therefore, TSP can be NP-hard, but it can't be NP-complete.

On the other hand, the Hamiltonian path problem asks for a yes/no answer, and it happens to be in NP. Therefore, since it's NP-hard as well, it's NP-complete.

Now, you can take TSP and convert it to a decision problem by changing the question from "what's the cheapest path?" to "is there a path that costs X or less?," and that latter formulation is in NP and also happens to be NP-complete.